# Ubuntu 16.04 sound problem

Tags: 16.04, sound

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. I come from Windows 10 where everything worked fine (front/read jacks and headphones).

Now on Ubuntu, if I connect the headphones in the back, I get no sound at all. I tried `sudo alsamixer force-reload` without success.

I connected the headphones in the front and the sound is working, but in the sound settings at `Output` at `Play sound through`, there is no device and i cannot control sound volume and stuff like that.

Now with a second pair of headphones I tried the front and rear jacks at the same time and the sound comes through the rear jack and in the sound settings at Play sound through it appears Line-Out (build in audio) and if I disconnect the front headphones then I got no sound in the back.

In alsamixer everything appears to be fine. Nothing is muted.

Comment: This lacks basic information, what is your Computer? What kind of Audio device does it have? Also add the output of `aplay -l` so we can see your devices.

Comment: **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: VT1705 Analog [VT1705 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 2: VT1705 Alt Analog [VT1705 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Please edit your question with the output and format it correctly with {} It is hard for people to read in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, (I learned it from a video on YouTube) when you *suspend* your system and turn it on back you will start to hear the sound. I've tried just now when I was searching for a solution and it's working.